# How to pass 2 or more data to ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

In a form how to pass two or more data by ajax in on click to controller

Html code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <input type="hidden" name="valdte" value="<?php echo $todate; ?>">
  <label for="">Sort By</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="picker">
<option>-----Select--------</option>
<option value="1">Executive</option>
<option value="2">Location</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="new_in" class="form-group col-md-4"></div>
```

the ajax code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#picker').on('change', function() {
      var StateID = $(this).val();
      console.log(StateID);
      if (StateID) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'sort_by',
          data: 'id=' + StateID,
          success: function(html) {
            $('#new_in').html(html);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('tbody').html('<option value="">Select View by first</option>');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

How pass the hidden filed value to these function any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it as

```
<input type="hidden" id="valdte" name="valdte" value="<?php echo $todate; ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#picker').on('change', function() {
      var StateID = $(this).val();
      var data1_value = $('#valdte').val();
      var data2_value = "bcd";
      var data3_value = "ety";
      console.log(StateID);
      if (StateID) {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'sort_by',
            data:{data1:data1_value,data2:data2_value,data3:data3_value,id:StateID},
            success:function(html){
                 $('#new_in').html(html);
            }
        });
      } else {
        $('tbody').html('<option value="">Select View by first</option>');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: how to take the input value in script